# Issue with for loop of checkboxes

Tags: php

I have series of checkboxes whom value I am taking and generating a string like....if checkbox is selected I add '1' to string and if it is not selected I add '0' to string.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="auth_0" id="auth_0" class="checkboxes" value="Yes"/>
```

My php script is...

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["save"])) {
/*      echo $_REQUEST['auth_0'];*/
   for ($i = 0; $i <= 49; $i++) {
        if ($_REQUEST['auth_[$i]'] == 'Yes') {
            $auth_string .= '1';
        } else {
            $auth_string .= '0';
        }
    }
    echo $auth_string;
}
```

Though string is generating but its value is always 0 in both cases that if checkbox is selected or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    if ($_REQUEST['auth_[$i]'] == 'Yes') {
    //            ^---------^--- should be " instead
```

using `'` tells PHP to not parse/interpolate variable values inside the string. use `"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quotes for string interpolation to work. Also, you don't use brackets for array subscripting.

You probably want (judging by your HTML example)...

```
$_REQUEST["auth_$i"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($_REQUEST['auth_'.[$i]] == 'Yes') {
```

this will work for you too.. above mentioned answers will also work .

Answer (score 1):

In HTML you have `id="auth_0"` and in PHP you check for `auth_[$i]` - see the square brackets. Also, you have apostrophes in `$_REQUEST['auth_[$i]']` which does not interpolate `$i`'s value - change that to double quotes